# Java code to join lines in PostgreSQL : No results were returned by the query

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, java

I have a line layer named verlegte_trasse in PostgreSQL that contains a lot of lines. I want to join the lines that are connected and have same value in attribute field 'bemerkung' in a new table named 'merged_verlegte_trasse'. I have a written a SQL code that works fine in PostgreSQL.

Now I have a web-app and I want to send a request through Java code to get the joined layer in my web-app. Even though my SQL works in PostgreSQL but it doesn't return any result via Java. All the connection parameters are fine. Here is my Java code:

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
       <%      
String driver = "org.postgresql.Driver";
String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/" + request.getParameter("DB_Name");
String username = "postgres";
String password = "*****";
Connection myConnection = null;
PreparedStatement myPreparedStatement = null;
ResultSet myResultSet = null;
Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
myConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
Statement st;
ResultSet rs;
st = myConnection.createStatement();
        String query =  "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS merged_verlegte_trasse; "+
                        "CREATE TABLE merged_verlegte_trasse ( "+
                        "  bemerkung text, "+
                        "  geom geometry, "+
                        "  sort text "+
                        "); "+
                        "INSERT INTO merged_verlegte_trasse (bemerkung, geom, sort) "+
                        "select bemerkung, (st_dump(st_linemerge(st_union(geom)))).geom, 'tiefbau'  "+
                        "from verlegte_trasse  "+
                        "group by bemerkung; "+
                        "Select * from merged_verlegte_trasse";
        
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        ResultSetMetaData  meta = rs.getMetaData();
Integer columncount = meta.getColumnCount();
       %>
[
      <% while(rs.next()){ %>
     {
  <% for (int i = 1 ; i<=columncount; i++)
{
%>
 <% if (i>1){%>,<% } %>
"<%= meta.getColumnName(i)%>":"<%= rs.getString(meta.getColumnName(i))%>"
    <% } %>
}
      <% if (!rs.isLast()){%>,<% } %>
       <% } %>
]
```

It should be mentioned that:

- The code creates a new table and save the merged lines in merged_verlegte_trasse.
- But it doesn't show the last line "Select * from merged_verlegte_trasse".
- If I delete all other lines and just type "Select * from merged_verlegte_trasse" it shows all the rows in this new table correctly.

Comment: I know nothing about Java, but why don't you just do one Select statement from the actual source table (verlegte_trasse)? You say the "select * from merged..." works when it is the only statement in the SQL request. You could replace it by "select bemerkung,(st_dump(  ...  group by bemerkung; " and it should work. In a multi-statement request, I assume your "rs" contains more than the "Select * result"

Comment: @Kasper because i need the merged layer in another applications like qgis to do something with it

Comment: Got it. If you have the Postgresql data at hand, you could create a View along your defintion of "merged_verlegte_trasse", to directly access whatever you need from QGIS or a web app without requiring any external code to run to keep it updated. This is much more efficient than droping, creating, populating a Table again and again. Otherwise, QGIS is able to run the "merged" request as well from the source Table, using the Data Source Manager and using your SQL query for "merge"

Comment: @kasper I changed the code based an your idea to this: CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW merged As
select bemerkung, (st_dump(st_linemerge(st_union(geom)))).geom 
from verlegte_trasse 
group by bemerkung;
select * from merged. It works in postgres but get the same error from java request:  No results were returned by the query

Comment: You might want to draw what your project's data pipeline is to figure out what the best solution is, and dive in the principles of Views: there is no need to create or replace them every time. Create it once from your SQL tool (or by running your script once). The Select from wherever you need (Qgis, web app, SQL tool). This  should solves your question from a data pipeline perspective. With regards to your Java code (not sure you need anything else than a single Select as per the 1st part of this comment), if you still want it to be multi statement, then it is a more a topic for Java forums.

Comment: Note that it violates best security practice to use the admin user to connect to a database from a service. Applications should not ever connect as `postgres`, particularly from a servlet; instead, create login roles to own an access the data, and group roles to manage access according to the "least privilege" principle. No web application should ever have rights to create tables or views (or indexes, which you fail to create).